# Sticky header & footer not that sticky

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a basic bootstrap 4, flex page which its navigation and footer should be sticky but its not and I cant figure out why:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link href="site.webmanifest" rel="manifest">
  <link href="icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <title>company</title>

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    #page-content {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }

    #sticky-footer {
      flex-shrink: none;
    }

    /* Other Classes for Page Styling */

    body {
      background: #007bff;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #0062E6, #33AEFF);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">

  <header>

    <div class="container">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top font-weight-light ">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Product 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Product 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">Services</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Service 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Service 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contacts</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Register</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>

  </header>





  <div id="page-content">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h1 class="font-weight-light mt-4 text-white">Sticky Footer using Flexbox</h1>
          <p class="lead text-white-50">Use just two Bootstrap 4 utility classes and three custom CSS rules and you will
            have a flexbox enabled sticky footer for your website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam, urna a molestie ornare, ligula lorem tristique nisi, at tempor ante ipsum a turpis. Donec pellentesque aliquet mauris, et laoreet nibh laoreet ut. In a turpis id eros commodo laoreet. Sed hendrerit elementum sagittis. Aliquam placerat arcu non rutrum rutrum. Maecenas eu lectus lacinia, consectetur justo vel, pharetra tortor. Vivamus fringilla porta magna vitae suscipit.

Nunc libero tortor, rhoncus vitae augue ut, auctor aliquam nunc. Donec laoreet, massa eget pellentesque feugiat, ex eros viverra massa, at gravida urna justo at tellus. Morbi vulputate nunc dolor, vitae dictum nibh maximus sed. Sed a massa est. Donec suscipit dolor at lobortis dictum. Mauris feugiat nunc vehicula mollis vehicula. Donec mattis blandit nisl, nec tristique tellus tristique quis. In lobortis est eu felis facilisis, eget finibus velit cursus. Sed faucibus congue congue.

Vivamus volutpat, leo vel scelerisque placerat, purus arcu malesuada enim, quis tempor mauris tellus sit amet sem. Fusce feugiat gravida orci. Etiam non dui sodales, sodales justo eget, varius diam. Nulla lectus leo, hendrerit eu urna id, commodo pulvinar odio. Quisque efficitur posuere urna non maximus. Fusce id purus lorem. Pellentesque molestie tortor non sagittis commodo. Praesent et augue tincidunt, porta diam vitae, lacinia orci. Quisque vehicula non nunc non tincidunt. Quisque magna turpis, gravida at interdum eu, rutrum accumsan ante.

Cras id sagittis nulla. Donec lacus augue, suscipit vel faucibus id, faucibus in lorem. Suspendisse semper augue a massa rhoncus, at ullamcorper diam porttitor. Vivamus ac urna nisi. Vivamus et odio interdum, faucibus nisi a, convallis nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed molestie, nunc ac cursus congue, metus quam blandit nisl, quis pulvinar augue dolor sollicitudin tortor. Praesent suscipit quis urna vel egestas. Praesent placerat quis nulla ac faucibus. Fusce facilisis, tortor id vestibulum tincidunt, orci elit egestas lorem, quis lacinia ante velit sed justo.

Etiam porttitor, eros tempor elementum vehicula, lorem dolor convallis urna, vitae efficitur diam nibh non felis. Nulla blandit viverra gravida. Aliquam bibendum magna risus, et consectetur leo tempor ut. Phasellus auctor faucibus quam, ut dignissim est tempor non. Sed sollicitudin ornare porttitor. Sed nibh est, tincidunt vitae felis dictum, bibendum feugiat magna. Mauris vitae libero sed neque mollis luctus vel eu augue. Praesent a lacus quis nisi pretium gravida vel sit amet sapien. Quisque ut sodales turpis. In ornare nisl sed auctor tempus. Sed eleifend efficitur erat in ullamcorper. Vivamus rutrum molestie lacus, in laoreet nibh placerat sed.
      </p>
    </div>


  </div>

  <footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <small>Copyright &copy; Your Website</small>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body class="d-flex flex-column">

</html>
```

I was on the impression that .sticky-top  class would sort out the situation for the top menu but cant figure out exactly what is causing this issue. How can I make sure that in below simple page both top menu bar and footer are sticky?

Answer (score 1):

For the sticky header, you add the class to `header` instead of `nav` as below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link href="site.webmanifest" rel="manifest">
  <link href="icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <title>company</title>

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    #page-content {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }

    #sticky-footer {
      flex-shrink: none;
    }

    /* Other Classes for Page Styling */

    body {
      background: #007bff;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #0062E6, #33AEFF);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">

  <header class="sticky-top ">

    <div class="container">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark font-weight-light ">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Product 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Product 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">Services</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Service 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Service 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contacts</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Register</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>

  </header>





  <div id="page-content">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h1 class="font-weight-light mt-4 text-white">Sticky Footer using Flexbox</h1>
          <p class="lead text-white-50">Use just two Bootstrap 4 utility classes and three custom CSS rules and you will
            have a flexbox enabled sticky footer for your website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam, urna a molestie ornare, ligula lorem tristique nisi, at tempor ante ipsum a turpis. Donec pellentesque aliquet mauris, et laoreet nibh laoreet ut. In a turpis id eros commodo laoreet. Sed hendrerit elementum sagittis. Aliquam placerat arcu non rutrum rutrum. Maecenas eu lectus lacinia, consectetur justo vel, pharetra tortor. Vivamus fringilla porta magna vitae suscipit.

Nunc libero tortor, rhoncus vitae augue ut, auctor aliquam nunc. Donec laoreet, massa eget pellentesque feugiat, ex eros viverra massa, at gravida urna justo at tellus. Morbi vulputate nunc dolor, vitae dictum nibh maximus sed. Sed a massa est. Donec suscipit dolor at lobortis dictum. Mauris feugiat nunc vehicula mollis vehicula. Donec mattis blandit nisl, nec tristique tellus tristique quis. In lobortis est eu felis facilisis, eget finibus velit cursus. Sed faucibus congue congue.

Vivamus volutpat, leo vel scelerisque placerat, purus arcu malesuada enim, quis tempor mauris tellus sit amet sem. Fusce feugiat gravida orci. Etiam non dui sodales, sodales justo eget, varius diam. Nulla lectus leo, hendrerit eu urna id, commodo pulvinar odio. Quisque efficitur posuere urna non maximus. Fusce id purus lorem. Pellentesque molestie tortor non sagittis commodo. Praesent et augue tincidunt, porta diam vitae, lacinia orci. Quisque vehicula non nunc non tincidunt. Quisque magna turpis, gravida at interdum eu, rutrum accumsan ante.

Cras id sagittis nulla. Donec lacus augue, suscipit vel faucibus id, faucibus in lorem. Suspendisse semper augue a massa rhoncus, at ullamcorper diam porttitor. Vivamus ac urna nisi. Vivamus et odio interdum, faucibus nisi a, convallis nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed molestie, nunc ac cursus congue, metus quam blandit nisl, quis pulvinar augue dolor sollicitudin tortor. Praesent suscipit quis urna vel egestas. Praesent placerat quis nulla ac faucibus. Fusce facilisis, tortor id vestibulum tincidunt, orci elit egestas lorem, quis lacinia ante velit sed justo.

Etiam porttitor, eros tempor elementum vehicula, lorem dolor convallis urna, vitae efficitur diam nibh non felis. Nulla blandit viverra gravida. Aliquam bibendum magna risus, et consectetur leo tempor ut. Phasellus auctor faucibus quam, ut dignissim est tempor non. Sed sollicitudin ornare porttitor. Sed nibh est, tincidunt vitae felis dictum, bibendum feugiat magna. Mauris vitae libero sed neque mollis luctus vel eu augue. Praesent a lacus quis nisi pretium gravida vel sit amet sapien. Quisque ut sodales turpis. In ornare nisl sed auctor tempus. Sed eleifend efficitur erat in ullamcorper. Vivamus rutrum molestie lacus, in laoreet nibh placerat sed.
      </p>
    </div>


  </div>

  <footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <small>Copyright &copy; Your Website</small>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body class="d-flex flex-column">

</html>
```

There is no `sticky-bottom` class but there are some tutorials to set a sticky footer, like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer/)

Comment: To add to this, if you want the header to span across the page, take it out of your content wrapper [like this](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/mdyxxOQ)

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be just add `position: sticky; bottom: 0` to `<footer>` tag

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link href="site.webmanifest" rel="manifest">
  <link href="icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <title>company</title>

  <style>


    #sticky-footer {
      flex-shrink: none;
    }

    /* Other Classes for Page Styling */

    body {
      background: #007bff;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #0062E6, #33AEFF);
    }
    #sticky-footer {
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">

  <header class="sticky-top">

    <div class="container">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark font-weight-light ">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Product 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Product 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">Services</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Service 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Service 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contacts</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Register</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>

  </header>





  <div id="page-content">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h1 class="font-weight-light mt-4 text-white">Sticky Footer using Flexbox</h1>
          <p class="lead text-white-50">Use just two Bootstrap 4 utility classes and three custom CSS rules and you will
            have a flexbox enabled sticky footer for your website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam, urna a molestie ornare, ligula lorem tristique nisi, at tempor ante ipsum a turpis. Donec pellentesque aliquet mauris, et laoreet nibh laoreet ut. In a turpis id eros commodo laoreet. Sed hendrerit elementum sagittis. Aliquam placerat arcu non rutrum rutrum. Maecenas eu lectus lacinia, consectetur justo vel, pharetra tortor. Vivamus fringilla porta magna vitae suscipit.

Nunc libero tortor, rhoncus vitae augue ut, auctor aliquam nunc. Donec laoreet, massa eget pellentesque feugiat, ex eros viverra massa, at gravida urna justo at tellus. Morbi vulputate nunc dolor, vitae dictum nibh maximus sed. Sed a massa est. Donec suscipit dolor at lobortis dictum. Mauris feugiat nunc vehicula mollis vehicula. Donec mattis blandit nisl, nec tristique tellus tristique quis. In lobortis est eu felis facilisis, eget finibus velit cursus. Sed faucibus congue congue.

Vivamus volutpat, leo vel scelerisque placerat, purus arcu malesuada enim, quis tempor mauris tellus sit amet sem. Fusce feugiat gravida orci. Etiam non dui sodales, sodales justo eget, varius diam. Nulla lectus leo, hendrerit eu urna id, commodo pulvinar odio. Quisque efficitur posuere urna non maximus. Fusce id purus lorem. Pellentesque molestie tortor non sagittis commodo. Praesent et augue tincidunt, porta diam vitae, lacinia orci. Quisque vehicula non nunc non tincidunt. Quisque magna turpis, gravida at interdum eu, rutrum accumsan ante.

Cras id sagittis nulla. Donec lacus augue, suscipit vel faucibus id, faucibus in lorem. Suspendisse semper augue a massa rhoncus, at ullamcorper diam porttitor. Vivamus ac urna nisi. Vivamus et odio interdum, faucibus nisi a, convallis nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed molestie, nunc ac cursus congue, metus quam blandit nisl, quis pulvinar augue dolor sollicitudin tortor. Praesent suscipit quis urna vel egestas. Praesent placerat quis nulla ac faucibus. Fusce facilisis, tortor id vestibulum tincidunt, orci elit egestas lorem, quis lacinia ante velit sed justo.

Etiam porttitor, eros tempor elementum vehicula, lorem dolor convallis urna, vitae efficitur diam nibh non felis. Nulla blandit viverra gravida. Aliquam bibendum magna risus, et consectetur leo tempor ut. Phasellus auctor faucibus quam, ut dignissim est tempor non. Sed sollicitudin ornare porttitor. Sed nibh est, tincidunt vitae felis dictum, bibendum feugiat magna. Mauris vitae libero sed neque mollis luctus vel eu augue. Praesent a lacus quis nisi pretium gravida vel sit amet sapien. Quisque ut sodales turpis. In ornare nisl sed auctor tempus. Sed eleifend efficitur erat in ullamcorper. Vivamus rutrum molestie lacus, in laoreet nibh placerat sed.
      </p>
    </div>


  </div>

  <footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <small>Copyright &copy; Your Website</small>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body class="d-flex flex-column">

</html>
```